# UV stretching on splines

Tags: uv, vector-mapping

I'm trying to apply a UV map on a spline and it looks like auto-UVs get stretched anywhere where distance between vertices is greater. Is there any way to get around that, I'm looking to create and extruded spline with consistent pattern.

[image: a busy cat]

Thank you!